Flow is not trigger while move email to the specific folder
I will need something like when a new email arrives the flow should create one item to the SharePoint list. I have created some rules for moving the email to specific folders based on the email address.
For Example,

Company1 Folder

User1 Folder.
User2 Folder


Company2 Folder

User1 Folder.
User2 Folder



I have created a Flow in Power Automate to achieve this. It is working as expected if the email is in the Inbox.
But if the email is moved to a specific folder (shown in the above example) as per the created rule then the flow is not triggered.
Can anyone help with the same?
Thanks

you can change the mailbox that the flow listens to

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the mailbox?

can you share your flow?

The behavior you're experiencing occurs because the "When a new email arrives" trigger in Power Automate by default only works for the Inbox folder unless explicitly configured for other folders. Emails moved to subfolders by rules may not trigger the flow unless explicitly set up to monitor those folders.
To address this issue, you can modify your flow or use an alternative trigger. Here's how you can make your flow work for emails in specific folders:

Modify the Flow Trigger by replacing the "When a new email arrives" trigger with the trigger: "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)" or "When a new email arrives in a folder".

